# Susy: Error using nth-omega mixin

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

I thought this would work:

```
.col4 {@include span-columns(3,12); @include nth-omega();}
```

But I get this error message (in CodeKit):

error screen.scss (Line 195 of _support.scss: Mixin with-only-support-for takes 6 arguments but 8 were passed.)

Without '@include nth-omega();' I don't get an error message. '@include nth-omega(4);' did not work either.

Comment: You're right. That should work. The problem is too many mixins attempting to adjust browser support settings - using the same method and causing a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Susy < 1.0.4 had an error regarding nth-omega which might be what you're seeing. Which version of Compass and Susy are you using? Try updating both with `> sudo gem update`.

Comment: Thanks, Oskar but I am using the latest versions: compass-0.13.alpha.0 and susy-1.0.4.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was actually dual Compass/Susy. I fixed it both places, but the new Compass gem hasn't been released yet. If you build your own gem from the master branch of Compass, it will work. And, supposedly, the new gem is coming real soon.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. Building my own gem is a bit over my skillset at the moment (just starting out with this whole Sass Compass Susy thing) so I will wait for it to be released. For now, using &:last-child {@include omega;} works fine.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, also updating both gems didn't fix it.